# Saving R6 class template within R package

Tags: r

I am making a package which uses an `R6` class.

As part of the internal data of the package I have a list of objects of my `R6` class. I have a script in `data-raw` that has the class template, in which I generate some objects (all of the same class) and the list.

One of the functions of the package allows users to add a new object to this list, so I want to be able to build a new object from the same template.

I thought I'd save the class template within the internal data using

```r
usethis::use_data(CT,overwrite=TRUE,internal=TRUE)
```

where `CT` is my class template.

This doesn't seem to work - when I install and load the package I can't find `CT` when doing `myPackage:::CT`, so I guess it's not possible to save a template as data.

Does anyone know the correct way of doing this?

Thanks.